# How can I determine the manufacturer of these cabinet doors?

Tags: cabinets

We have a couple of kitchen cabinets that our dog chewed the corners off of. Our landlord is giving us a chance to find replacement doors before he charges us for a whole new set of cabinets.

The problem we're running into is that we can't identify the door model or manufacturer. Our landlord purchased the cabinets a couple of years ago and doesn't know the manufacturer.

[image: This is what the door bevel looks like.]

Does this look familiar to anyone? If so do you know the make and model?

Comment: I think your best bet is to push as hard as you can on getting the landlord to go through his shoebox of receipts. (Unless he's incredibly fly-by-night, those would be required for taxes, and one tends to keep a few years back.) And, fwiw, the only reasonable recourse would only be all new doors -- the cabinets didn't get chewed, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll ping the landlord again to see if he can go through his receipts. He's not quite fly-by-night, but I wouldn't put it past him to have thrown them away. Regarding the cabinets themselves you are correct, it was just the doors that were chewed. I'll look into the price of replacing all of the doors. We were able to find a door that looks almost exactly the same so we may be able to show it to our landlord and see if he's ok with it.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I am trying to find the same doors! Were you able to figure out who made them?

Answer (score 2):

Those are Thermofoil cabinet doors.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.